# VBA code to combine multiple worksheets mostly works, but is producing unexpected results

Tags: vba, excel

Scenario:  A workbook will have a variable number of worksheets, each with a variable number of populated cells, most commonly in Column A only but not necessarily. There is no header row.  I want to combine all the worksheets into a single "master" worksheet, after which I will perform various shenanigans later on. What I have "mostly" works, but for some reason it leaves Row 1 blank, which I do not want. I suppose I could just delete the empty row, but that seems awfully cheesy and doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that I don't understand why it's doing this.

Code:

```
Private Sub cmdFinalize_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim final As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colCount As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set final = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    final.Name = "Final"
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    colCount = ws.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Index = wb.Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
        final.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I assumed the Offset(1) was causing the problem, but removing it entirely causes the *last* row item of every worksheet to be overwritten by the first line of the next one when it all gets glued together on the 'Master' worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use offset(1) only for second and after worksheet.

Following code use a flag to indicate the processing worksheet is first or not.

```
Private Sub cmdFinalize_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim final As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colCount As Integer

    Dim firstWorksheetFlag as boolean  'Flag to indicate the first worksheet is in process
    firstWorksheetFlag = True          ' Flag is true at begin

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set final = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    final.Name = "Final"
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    colCount = ws.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Index = wb.Worksheets.Count Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
        If firstWorksheetFlag 'Offset(1) is not used.
            final.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
            firstWorksheetFlag = False ' first worksheet has been processed, so next is not first.
        Else 'second or later worksheet, so Offset(1) is used.
            final.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count,rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```